# Java multithreading not closing threads

Tags: java

I have the following code in a command line application. Once the loop completes, my app is still running. Why is it not shutting down. From the logs, I can see that endIndex has reached. But the app is still running?

```
Executor exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
for (int i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++) {
        final String spURL = urlPart + i;

        Runnable requestHandler = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    getImageForURL(spURL, 0);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }
        };
        exec.execute(requestHandler);
    }
```

Comment: Can you make sure that the function `getImageForURL` returns every time ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
ExecutorService e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
...
e.shutdown();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to shutdown the executors after the loop (ideally in a `finally` block):
`exec.shutdown()` or `exec.shutdownNow()`